# How do I pass a structure array from one function to another?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing array of structure as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800993/passing-array-of-structure-as-a-function-parameter)

What is the best way to pass one structure array from one function to another?

Lets say I have

```
funcion1(){
   struct album_ {
   int num_tracks;
   struct tracks_ tracks;
   int playlist_hits[];
   };
   typedef struct album_ album;
   album all_album[50];
}

function2(){
}
```

How would I pass `all_album[50];` to function2()?

Comment: But it was created in another function.

Answer (score 2):

struct is like any other *type*. You can just pass it like how you pass an integer array. If you declare (like above) as global, you don't need to pass at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
void myFunc( album* A, int N )
{
   int i;
   for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
      A[i].num_tracks = 0;
}

void main()
{
   album MyAlbums[50];
   myFunc( MyAlbums, 50 );
}
```

Comment: instead of `50` in the call to `myFunc()` you could use `sizeof MyAlbums / sizeof *MyAlbums` and avoid another use of a magic constant :)

Comment: pmg is right, but only for arrays on the stack. sizeof() should never be applied to malloc'd or new'd arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As either an array of fixed-size, or as a pointer and size pair.

```
struct tracks_ {
};

struct album_ {
  int num_tracks;
  struct tracks_ tracks;
  int playlist_hits[];
};
typedef struct album_ album;
album all_album[50];

void foo(album all_album[50]) {
 //passes this way
}

void foo2(album* all_album, size_t size) { //or degrades to a pointer
}

int main() {
   foo(all_album);
   foo2(all_album, 50);
}
```

Comment: `foo` isn't doing what you think it's doing.  In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are identical to `T *a`; in the function `foo`, `all_album` is a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

For passing any array of type `T` to a function, you generally write a function that accepts a pointer to T and a separate size parameter:

```
void foo(album *a, size_t size) { ... }
```

to which you pass the array expression and a size:

```
int main(void)
{
  ...
  album all_album [N];
  ...
  foo(all_album , sizeof all_album / sizeof *all_album )
  ...
}
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be replaced with an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element of the array.

IOW, when you write

```
foo(all_album, sizeof all_album / sizeof *all_album);
```

several things happen.

1. The first `all_album` expression is replaced with a pointer expression whose value is `&all_album[0]`; this is why the type of `a` in the definition for `foo` has type `album *`.
2. The `sizeof all_album` expression evaluates to the total number of bytes in the array.  Since `all_album` is an operand of the `sizeof` operator, it is *not* converted to a pointer expression.
3. The `sizeof *all_album` expression evaluates to the number of bytes in a *single* object of type `album`.  Since `all_album` is *not* an operand of `sizeof` (the *expression* `*all_album` is the operand), it is first converted to an expression of type "pointer to `album`".  The `*` operand is applied to that pointer expression, yielding a new expression of type `album`, which is evaluated by `sizeof`.
4. `sizeof all_album / sizeof *all_album` is evaluated, yielding the number of *elements* in the array.  This value is what gets passed as the `size` parameter in the definition of `foo`.